# Access to an IBOutlet in a modal view's parent view

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, modalviewcontroller

I have an iOS app where my architecture is:

```
VC1 => MVC1
```

I want to access to an VC1's IBOutlet (aboutBtn). I tried making a delegate in MVC1 and setting VC1 as delegate, but I still can't access it. How would I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just create an instance variable in MVC1 and pass the IBOutlet variable you're trying to access from VC1 to MVC1. For example, you could call something like `MVC1.referenceToSomeIBOutlet = self.someIBOutlet` from VC1. That will give MVC1 access to the passed in IBOutlet object.

Comment: Did that just before you post the answer :P it works, so I'll accept your answer ;)