# Unable to access iboutlets when called from other class

Tags: ios

I have two classes, and Class1 calls a method from Class2, like this:

```
Class2 *c = [[Class2 alloc] init];
[c cMethod];
[c release];
```

The method get called, but if I try to access an IBOutlet, nothing happens.

```
self.outlet.text = @"asdf";
```

However, when I do it from viewDidLoad, it works.

```
[self c];
```

Comment: I posted an answer to a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434027/access-to-an-iboutlet-in-a-modal-views-parent-view/7434288#7434288). Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

You're apparently expecting the instance of Class2 you create above to be somehow mysteriously linked to a previously created instance of Class2 that is bound to an IBOutlet.

Please ask your professor to explain to you how different instances of a class are, indeed, different.

Comment: I dont have a professor. But thanks!  How would i go about doing this.

Comment: Well go back and reread whatever reference you material you have on objects and object-oriented programming.